# In DeltaTables, why does append mode with mergeSchema create a full copy of the data in storage?

Tags: pyspark, parquet, azure-synapse, delta-lake

I'm working with synapse notebooks and pyspark and I'm trying to support schema evolution in an efficient manner. The format doesn't have to necessarily be DeltaTables but it seems like a natural choice for incremental data load.

This is the code I'm using:

```
                new_delta = spark.read.format('delta').load(delta_table_path)
                new_delta.withColumn('test1', lit(None).cast('string')) \
                    .withColumn('test2', lit(None).cast('string')) \
                    .write.format('delta') \
                    .mode('append').option('mergeSchema', 'true') \
                    .save(delta_table_path)
```

and the result is:
[image]
[image]

Looking into the files, the older files have the old schema, and the new files have the new schema.

My expectation here would be that using the append mode and mergeSchema would only update the schema, without creating full history of the data.

Running vacuum will clean up the old data but I'd like to avoid (if possible) writing potentially large volume of data to storage unecessarily.

Using overwrite mode with overwriteSchema has the same behaviour as described above.

Am I misunderstanding how DeltaTables work, should I use a different approach if I'm trying to support schema evolution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you're not doing it correctly - you read all your data, added columns, and then wrote the all data back in append mode, creating a copy of the data.

There are different approaches to adding new columns:

- instead of writing data in the `append` mode, you can overwrite the existing data. But this still will duplicate files in storage
- Depending on the version of the Delta table you use, you can use built-in functions to add new columns - you need to use SQL syntax for that (see [docs](https://docs.delta.io/latest/delta-batch.html#add-columns)):

```py
# Let's generate some data
>>> spark.range(10).write.format("delta").mode("append").saveAsTable("test")
>>> df = spark.read.table("test")
>>> df.printSchema()
root
 |-- id: long (nullable = true)
# Update table
>>> spark.sql("ALTER TABLE test ADD COLUMNS (col1 int, col2 string)")
DataFrame[]
# Check that schema changed and we see new columns
>>> df = spark.read.table("test")
>>> df.printSchema()
root
 |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- col1: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- col2: string (nullable = true)
>>> df.show(2)
+---+----+----+
| id|col1|col2|
+---+----+----+
|  3|null|null|
|  4|null|null|
+---+----+----+
```

- Or you can simply modify your code to add new columns, and when you'll write data next time, use `mergeSchema` set to `true`, and schema will be updated. - so-called [automatic schema evolution](https://docs.delta.io/latest/delta-batch.html#automatic-schema-update).

I personally would recommend to use 2nd method.

P.S. There is also a possibility to rename & delete columns - you need to enable [column mappings for that](https://docs.delta.io/latest/delta-column-mapping.html).

Comment: Of course I was overthinking it, simply using the new dataframe as a base for the save operation loaded the data as expected. Thank you for your help.

Comment: yes, also the `df = spark.read...; add columns ; df.limit(0).write....` should work